# I'm trying to write a VNC server and client in java. I have a few questions

Tags: java, remote-access, remote-desktop, vnc, screensharing

I want to write a VNC client and server as i think i will get to learn a lot. I would want to do this in JAVA however I saw somewhere that this isn't possible. I'd want to use C++ for parts that aren't possible in JAVA. I'm a little confused about where to begin. I saw TightVNC,RealVNC etc but the code base is too large for me to make sense. I see that the RFB specifies the packet [types](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vncjlgpl)  So could someone help me get started? How do I go about writing code to make the packet formats of any use? Also could anyone explain if [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vncjlgpl/) is a VNC server?

I have another question:
If i ditch RFB can i write

1. A server application: which basically captures everything on the screen and sends it to the client every few milliseconds. (Robot screencapture is too slow) And waits for mouse movements and keystrokes.
2. A client application that sends mouse movements and keystokes to the server and displays the screen of the server.
   However I'm worried about synchornization.

Comment: If you find the code bases of an existing application too complex, I wouldn't assume that if you wrote it yourself it would be less complex.  You are going to have to understand everything the existing applications are doing.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for the reply. Yes indeed, but i would work on the application over a period of few months, writing one part at a time. These projects are built by several people over years. I just want to write a basic setup. I'm not aiming for a commercial product.